# AudioTrack sound loss while screen lock in nexus 5

Tags: android, stream, streaming, wifi, audiotrack

i am creating live audio streaming using wifi. hence i use AudioTrack object but when i doing screen lock some device loss the audio. in nexus 5 with Android Marshmallow and also same issue occurring in  Android Lollipop Device but not in all.

Working fine in nexus 4, android one, galaxy S4.

Please help me. sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

i found simple solution, audio streaming stop while screen sleep.

i set below code in my service.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    MulticastLock multicastLock;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        PowerManager pMgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pMgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        WifiManager wMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiLock = wMgr.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF,
                "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();

        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("multicastLock");
        multicastLock.acquire();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (multicastLock != null) {
            multicastLock.release();
            multicastLock = null;
        }
        if (wifiLock != null) {
            wifiLock.release();
            wifiLock = null;
        }
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
            wakeLock = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```